# login form in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, json, authentication

I was trying to implement login form by authenticating the credentials from data stored in json file. But i'm getting error like only first case is working.It's just a demo application trying to learn the concepts:
 this is my controller:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller("myCtrl",function($scope, $http)
 {  
      $scope.check = function(){
           var sample;
                     $http.get('roles.json').then(function(res)
                     {
                        sample = res.data;

                    console.log(sample);

                    angular.forEach(sample, function(val)
                    {
                       if($scope.uName===val.userName)
                       {
                           if($scope.password===val.password)
                           {
                               alert("sucess");
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               alert("failure");
                           }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           alert("failure");
                       }

                  });
              }); // end of http
       };// end of function   
 });
```

data is loading properly but seems like some problem in logic.
data in json:

```
[
  {"userName":"stud101","password":"stud1","role":"student"},
  {"userName":"stud102","password":"stud2","role":"student"},
  {"userName":"superlib","password":"lib1","role":"Librarian"}
  ]
```

I'm getting success only with first case, in rest other cases failure.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? What is the exact Error message?

Comment: There is no point having a login if you are going to send passwords and usernames to the browser. Anyone can see them. With that being said...show us what the data looks like so we can help make what you do have work

Comment: your condition is checking both uName and password is equal to val or not , Its seems bit odd .Please check that

Answer (score 1):

```
$http.get('roles.json').then(function(res){
   sample = res.data;

   console.log(sample);
   var isMatched = false;
   angular.forEach(sample, function(val)
   {
     if($scope.uName==val.userName && $scope.password==val.password)
     {
        isMatched = true;
         return false; // To stop the foreach loop if username and password both are matched.
     }


   });
   if(isMatched)
   {
    alert("success");
   }
else
{
    alert("failure");
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
angular.forEach($scope.messagepool, function(value, key) {
  if(value.userName==$scope.uName  && value.password==$scope.password){
    alert('success');
  }else{
    alert('faluire');
  } 
});
```

Use this instead of your foreach . Hope this helps (y)